# How to load and render a webform with Ajax

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm new on Drupal 8, and I want to make a custom module to load any webform of (webform module) on other pages of the website.

The idea is to load the webform when the page load. All webform has configured with ajax submission.

I don't know how I can do that. I someone can help me. I'm on Drupal 8

---

I've create a custom module with a custom path in `routing.yml`:

```
path: '/webform-data/{webformid}'
```

In my controller I've created a public function to retrieve the webform by id.

I want for example create a link, like:

```
<a href="/webform-data/{webformid}">Click</a>
```

When I click on the link, the webform load in a wrapper, but when I submit the webform, I have a redirection to the path of webform and I don't want the redirection. I just want the inline confirm message without reloading the page.

I have this in my controller :

```
// Controller
namespace Drupal\ajax_webform\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AjaxWebformController extends ControllerBase {

    public function getWebform($webformid) {

        $build['webform'] = [
            '#type' => 'webform',
            '#webform' => $webformid
        ];

        $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
        $rendered = $renderer->renderRoot($build);

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent($rendered);
        return $response;
    }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, you need to clarify and narrow down your question.

Comment: Could you paste the relevant code from that module?

Comment: I've create a custom module with a custom path in routin.yml:  path: '/webform-data/{webformid}'. In my controller I've created a public function to retrive the webform by Id. I want for example create a link, like <a href="/webform-data/{webformid}">Click</a>. When I click on the link, the webform load in a wrapper, but when I submit the webform, I have a redirection to the path of webform and I don't want the redirection. I just want the inline confirm message without reloading the page.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the basic code of a controller which loads and renders a webform with ajax:

```
  public function getWebform($webformid) {

    $build['webform'] = [
      '#type' => 'webform',
      '#webform' => $webformid,
    ];

    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#webform-wrapper', $build));

    return $response;
  }
```

The link ajaxified by adding the class `use-ajax`:

```
<a href="/webform-data/{webformid}" class="use-ajax">Click</a>
```

You need the library `core/drupal.ajax` for the page containing this link and a `<div id="webform-wrapper"></div>` as target.

Comment: Thanks 4K4, I can load the webform on my page, but if I'm not authenticated (anonymous user) , I can't submit the form, its return this error : An error occurred while attempting to process /webform-data/ajax_webform?.

Comment: It works well. However in the controller, it has to handle the submission too, otherwise the submit will redirect the main page to an Ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [Ajax links API](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_links_api).
Sadly, there is an issue with the Webform module and BigPipe that needs to be [fixed](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3016619).

Comment: Thank you jrockowitz, I will try to look the Ajax Api, but I think there is a problem with the template, because in the librairies.yml there is no dependencies. I'm not the first developer.